# Does a minor need to be present to apply for a passport in Colombia?

Tags: passports, colombia, colombian-citizens

Does a minor need to be present to apply for a passport in person in Colombia?

Comment: Hi Bob, is this for travel purpose or do you plan to immigrate to Colombia?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I suspect it's for travel, given that it's tagged [tag:colombian-citizens].